# Ansible HTML parsing and grep for data with Jinja Filters

Tags: ansible

I am actually trying to parse a HTML URI GET response using Jinja filters in Ansible for a particular attribute present in the response

I was able to use the search, regex_replace the tags h3 and tag i with ' ' but not sure how to take the rest of the tags like below

```
 - name: HTML output
      set_fact: response="{{ webpage.results | map(attribute='content')| select('search', '<h3>')|map('regex_replace', '<h3>(.*)</h3>', '\\1')| select('search', '<i>')| map('regex_replace', '<i>(.*)</i>', '\\1')| list }}"
      register: response
      with_indexed_items: "{{ groups['host-group-name'] }}"
```

current HTML "response" format

```
<!--
  ~ Copyright (c) xxxxxx.  All rights reserved.
  -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=xxxxxx">
    <title>xxxxxxxx</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx" data-xxxx="xxxx|xxxx|xxxx|xx,,|"></script></head>
<body>
<h3>Item1 : <i>xxxxxx</i></h3>
<h3>Item2 : <i>xxxxx</i></h3>
<h3>Item3 : <i>xxxxx</i></h3>
<h3>Item4: <i>${xxxxx}</i></h3>
<h3>Item5 : <i>xxxxxx</i></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get only the "Item2: Value" or just the "Value" associated with Item2 from the HTML page response displayed (or) registered by the ansible playbook

Comment: Your HTML "response" is not HTML. Too many backslashes.

Comment: Use a dedicated tool to parse HTML: `xmllint --html --xpath '//h3[2]/text()' response.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xmllint`, as @ceving suggested, but rather than selecting an item by index you can use an XPath expression to find the element that contains your target value.  For example, to find that `h3` element that contains `Item2`:

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//h3[contains(text(), "Item2")]/text()' data.html
```

Which gives us:

```
Item2: Value
```

From which it is trivial to extract just the value. We can wrap this up in a playbook like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: parse html
      command: xmllint --html --xpath '//h3[contains(text(), "Item2")]/text()' -
      args:
        stdin: "{{ webpage.results }}"
      register: match

    - debug:
        var: match.stdout

    - set_fact:
        result: "{{ match.stdout.split(': ')[1] }}"

    - debug:
        var: result
```

You don't show it in your example HTML, but if the values are contained in `<i>` elements, as in `<h3><i>Item2: Value</i></h3>`, then you would simply change your xpath expression to look like:

```
//h3/i[contains(text(), "Item2")]/text()
```

**Update**

If your input HTML isn't valid, you have fewer options, mainly the regular-expression based solution you were originally working with. I would probably just throw it at `awk`, like this:

```
- command: >-
    awk -F"<>" '/Item2/ {print $4}'
  args:
    stdin: "{{ webpage.results }}"
  register: result
```

Given the example data you've presented in your question, this would end up with `result.stdout` = `xxxxx`.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I am newbee with xmllint and have tried to parse the xmllint the above HTML response(updated similar to the exact response) as suggested but its resulting in "HTML parser error-Misplaced tags". Please suggest.

Comment: That means that your input HTML is invalid. If you can't ensure valid input, you're going to have to go with your original idea of using some sort of regular-expression based solution to extract the data you want.

Comment: Yes from investigating it, the HTML seems to be passed in string format in a list which is causing xmllint to throw the error. I am trying to parse the string in Python but have a question on it. Can i include it here ?

Comment: You should probably open a new question for that.